# Is doing a database query in Woocommerce efficient to only display posts from a certain category?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On my WordPress website I want to create a "featured items" slider at the top, to fill the slider with posts my idea was to do a database query for all item posts with a certain category and display them within this. However this doesn't seem efficient and like I am skipping out main WordPress functionality.

Any other suggested ways of doing this would be appreciated, I know there is a woocommerce slider plugin however I would like this to be a custom feature.

Comment: When you say 'database query' do you mean an SQL query?  Or do you mean a `WP_Query`?

Comment: I was originally looking at an SQL query, is it safer to do it via a WP_Query?

Comment: Yes.  You absolutely should use, as an example, `$query = new WP_Query( $args );` when you're running a query for anything inherently built into WordPress.  There is a whole methodology of running unique/complex SQL queries within Wordpress, but for something like querying posts, WordPress already has all the tools in place for you. Tons of info here about all the options available to you: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/